# How to make a black and white inked effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, image-editing

I want to make normal looking pictures look like they were inked on paper, so give them a 'rough' inked look. Is it possible to achieve this effect in photoshop?

This the effect I want to achieve: 
[image]

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: What kind of "normal looking picture" do you start with? Do you have reason to believe these examples were also such a "normal" picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to get this effect, this can be a very simple one.

### Image

Make a Layer Via Copy of the original image and go to **Menu Adjustments** > **Desaturate**

[image: Desaturate]

### Paper and Ink

Make two *Solid Color Layers* with the paper color and the ink color. Apply a textured mask.

[image: Solid color layers]

This is a texture mask example made with Noise, Wind and Blur filters:

[image: Textured mask]

### Composition

Put the *Desaturated image* layer between the *paper* and the *ink* layers. Set a different blend mode: Hard Light in this example.

Mask the background.

Group the *Ink Layer* with the *desaturated image* and change the blend mode to Overlay.

[image: Composition]

Select the *Desaturated Image Layer* and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> Win to adjust highlights, midtones and shadows.

### Result

[image: End]

*Original picture from [unsplash.com](https://unsplash.com/photos/iMdsjoiftZo)*

Comment: Thank you! This is the kind of effect I wanted to achieve :)